# Mi Yodeya Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- A Havdalah candle
- Mi Yodeya die-cut, vinyl stickers (2.5" x 2.5")
- Mi Yodeya mini poster (6" x 6")
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address.

### The sticker

[image: judaism.stackexchange.com sticker]

### The poster

[image: judaism.stackexchange.com poster]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Ooh, thank you -- a holiday present! :-)  I'm looking forward to having Jin's fabulous art on my wall!

Comment: Missed it by that much... On page 3....

Comment: Not complaining at all; just curious: what prompted [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/1374/revisions)? (If it's something sensitive, feel free to delete this comment and respond in chat or not at all.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses for our other sites' top user swag packages, we typically do the standard site branded tshirt+stickers. Mi Yodeya is our first site with a strong cultural identity and we wanted to do something more appropriate and special. I added a 3rd item(the mini poster). After some more thoughts, we think instead of the tshirt, a Mi Yodeya custom boxed Havdalah candle is more appropriate. I don't have a mockup for the candle box yet. I'll try to post one as soon as I get something from our printshop.

Comment: @Jin Wow. You and the rest of the SE team are awesome. You should consider putting your signature into the work of art that is the mini-poster. Apparently, at least [two](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/mi-yodeya-top-user-swag#comment3867_1374) of [us](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/recommended-frame-for-the-mi-yodeya-mini-poster) are planning to hang it on our walls.

Comment: Yes, please sign the poster @Jin!

Comment: What will you do if there are any non-responses, i.e. extra Swag? If you will send to the next people in line please re-check page 2 in case people have moved up in line.

Comment: @Ariel We typically just keep it in reserve for site-related events, contests, etc.

Comment: I still haven't got a mail, did anyone got one? And yes, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @jutky Sorry about that - we're holding off on sending the email out until we finalize the package. Waiting on the whole candle thing to be figured out at the moment. Hopefully it won't take much longer. :)

Comment: No problem, take your time. I just was afraid that the mail haven't reached me for some reason.

Comment: If you are still selecting a candle, I have found the spiral twisted ones drip less than the braided ones.

Comment: Thank you for putting this together!

Comment: @jutky, I got the email today.

Comment: Thank you, what a sweet gesture!

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome!

Comment: Quick update on this: It took us a while to find the right packaging for the candle box, and the poster container. The swag will be in production very soon! I expect you'll receive the packages in a month or less. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Thank you. Received mine just the other day.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2248/5323, [please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142973/thinkgeek-onebox-support-for-chat#comment405943_142973) :)

Answer (score 8):

#### Thank you very much, and Happy Chanuka!

[image: Photo of framed copy of Mi Yodeya mini-poster]

Comment: ברצוני גם להודות להרב @יואל שליט"א על חתימתו האישי  במכתבו מיום ו' כסלו התשע"ג