# Recommended frame for the Mi Yodeya mini-poster

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, design

I plan to frame my Mi Yodeya mini-poster [when I get it](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/mi-yodeya-top-user-swag) and hang it in my house because:

- It's beautiful.
- I value my association with this community.
- It will serve as an ongoing promotion of the community.

Can you recommend a frame to use with this poster that will present it most attractively and durably at a minimum of cost?

Clearly this will be easier to answer once we have the actual artifacts in our hands, but maybe someone will have an idea already.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's site promotion

Comment: ... The more people who put this on their walls, the more prominently - the more MY will come up in conversations, introducing new people to the site and community.

Comment: Is this on-topic on the main site, since it's about Jewish life? (It's definitely *more* on-topic here,so I'm not proposing to move it. I'm just musing.)

Comment: @msh210, would "How should I frame this particular Chabad poster?" (or gadol picture, or what have you) be on-topic on Mi Yodeya? I'm thinking not; I'd close as "Too Localized," I think. The same would apply to this.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I brought this up to [Jin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/417/jin) in Chat. [He recommended](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6962057#6962057):

> since the poster is earthy tones, I think a maroon/dark brown frame will look nice with the poster

He then Googled a bit and came up with [a nice possibility](http://www.etsy.com/listing/62475459/6x6-square-picture-frame-with-vintage) on Etsy.

Etsy's nice, since vendors on it offer distinctive crafts, are frequently open to customization requests, and frequently charge very reasonable prices. (Note: Most sellers on Etsy are US-based and are set up best for shipping to the US.)

I searched Etsy for [`6x6 frame`](http://www.etsy.com/search?q=6x6%20frame&view_type=gallery) and discovered and ultimately ordered [this one](http://www.etsy.com/listing/104942721/solid-cedar-wood-6x6-picture-photo-craft), which looks like it will attractively and simply set off the poster and costs only $12.99 shipped.

Here it is:

[image: Photo of framed copy of the Mi Yodeya mini-poster]

It goes very well, I think, except that it overlaps the scrollwork on the border of the poster a bit.